# python os.scandir shows apple dmg, app, bundle as directory

Tags: python, macos, bundle, hidden, scandir

I'm writing a program for parallel file checksums. I'm stuck with subdirectories count because python os.scandir() shows Apple DMG, apps as directory.

So far I've got following code.

```
import os, sys

### variables
PATH_SRC = os.getcwd()
EXCLUDE_FILES = ('__', '.')
EXCLUDE_DIRS = ('__', '.', '*.app', '*.dmg')
LIST_FILES = []
LIST_DIRS = []

COUNT_DIRS = 0
COUNT_FILES = 0`

with os.scandir(PATH_SRC) as it:
  for entry in it:
    if not entry.name.startswith(EXCLUDE_FILES):
      if entry.is_dir() and entry.name.startswith(EXCLUDE_DIRS):
        LIST_DIRS.append(entry.path)
        COUNT_DIRS = COUNT_DIRS + 1
      elif entry.is_file():
        LIST_FILES.append(entry.path)
        COUNT_FILES = COUNT_FILES + 1

print ('Source path contains ', COUNT_DIRS, ' subdirectories.')
print ('Source path contains ', COUNT_FILES, ' file(s).')


print (LIST_DIRS)
print (LIST_FILES)
```

source path contains 10 subdirectories but above by mentioned code shows 16 because there is some apps, dmg and they are shown as directory.

I need to recursively list files inside the source path and exclude hidden and bundles (dmg,app). Count them...it would be used as decision whether to use parallelisation or not. I usually copy photos from flash cards but sometimes I copy whole try on my file server.

Idea behind it is...count all files inside source path...if there is more than 10 files for example...run parallel checksum of files...SSD can handle about >4 files at once and saturate CPU. My workstation has got 2 CPUs with 4 cores each...but there will be SSD bottleneck.

Furthermore RAID 10 file server can handle about 2-3 files at once.

I'm new to Python so don't be surprised about complicated code.

AlGORITM:
1. check how many files total and decide for MP (Multiprocessing or multithread)

2. recursively check source path, exclude hidden files and bundles...then run checksum sha512 on them
3. every dir/subdir must have own checksum file. I don't want one large checksum file in source path

I hope you understand. Please any suggestions?

Regards

Hajes

Answer (score 0):

"Apps" ("***.app**") are really directories.

[Take a look at Mac OS command](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ls.1.html) `ls` :

> ls -- list directory contents
>
> The following options are available:
>
> ...
>
> ```
> -F      Display a slash (`/') immediately after each pathname that is a directory, an asterisk (`*')
>          after each that is executable, an at sign (`@') after each symbolic link, an equals sign (`=')
>          after each socket, a percent sign (`%') after each whiteout, and a vertical bar (`|') after
>          each that is a FIFO
>  -G      Enable colorized output.  This option is equivalent to defining CLICOLOR in the environment.
>          (See below.)
> ```
>
> ...

#### Results for `User/Library` dir :

[image: User/Library]

Dirs are colored and appended by `/`

#### Results for `Applications` dir :

[image: Applications]

All apps `*.app` are dirs.

#### And results for other files :

[image: ### And results for other files]

`*.dmg` and `*.zip` are marked as executable for some reason.

Comment: there is ls -la from Mac

    drwxr-xr-x@   3 hajes  staff        102 Jul 24 11:07 ProStockMaster.pkg
    -rw-r--r--@   1 hajes  staff   69241878 Apr 19  2017 Qobuz.dmg
    drwxr-xr-x@   3 hajes  admin        102 Jul 24 11:06 LCC Installer.app

PKG, APP is directory...dmg is just disk image